# File not found error while executing a sqoop job

Tags: hadoop, import, sqoop

When I execute a sqoop job it throws a FileNotFoundException error as below

> 18/05/29 06:18:59 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/0ce66d1f09ce960a71c165855afbe42c/QueryResult.jar
>   18/05/29 06:18:59 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning query import.
>   18/05/29 06:18:59 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
>   18/05/29 06:18:59 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   18/05/29 06:18:59 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
>   18/05/29 06:19:01 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
>   18/05/29 06:19:01 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
>   18/05/29 06:19:01 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
>   18/05/29 06:19:01 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
>   18/05/29 06:19:01 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser1354549662/.staging/job_local1354549662_0001
>   18/05/29 06:19:01 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://svn-server:54310/home/hduser/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/lib/postgresql-9.2-1002-jdbc4.jar
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:99)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:269)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importQuery(SqlManager.java:729)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:499)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:228)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:283)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
>   `

It should look for jars and other dependencies in local `sqoop/lib` directory but it looks it in HDFS with the same file path as my local sqoop lib path. As per project requirement, I need sqoop to look into my local library. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the **SQOOP_HOME** and **PATH** environment variables for the sqoop in .bashrc file

if not Please add

> vi ~/.bashrc

include the below lines

```
export SQOOP_HOME=/your/path/to/the/sqoop

export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
```

save the file and execute the following command

> source ~/.bashrc

Hope this is helpfull to you!!!

Comment: Please let me know the sqoop command you have executed. That will help me identify the issue. Thank!!!